# VBA Regex - use \b and include "-" at the end of word boundary

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am not familiar with regex in VBA but have to debug a code written by someone else.

I understand that `\b` matches a position based on word boundaries and excludes non-word characters like `-`.

However, I need the code to match the `-` that are in some strings.

For example,

Match `cats and dogs` in the `search_criteria`: `i have cats and dogs` with the code:

```
"\b" & search_criteria & "\b"
```

works.

However, this doesn't come up with a match:

`dogs -`  in the `search_criteria`: `dogs - sleeping`
doesn't work.

The `search_criteria` is a list that contains strings that don't end with `-` and strings that end with `-`.

Like this:

```
dogs -  
cats -   
cats and dogs  
houses  
cars  
work -
```

I basically have to change the `\b` at the end of the code but need help with this:

```
"\b" & search_criteria & "\b"
```

Comment: It depends on what might follow the hyphen.  But `"\b" & search_criteria & "\b"`  where `search criteria` is a list as you show it, does not create a valid regex anyway.  You really need to show your code, and more complete data examples.  Once you develop a valid regex, you might be able to replace the terminal `\b` with `(?=\W|$)`, but you don't supply enough information to provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Also include an explanation which example input data you use and what the desired output is.

Comment: There are several online Regex resources, including https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/ where you can play around and test regexes. Be aware that they use regex engines that differ in the more advanced features, but should be OK for what you're doing if you are aware of the Dolllar and Caret usage being less common. FYI see https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/a-better-regex-engine-library-for-vba.1164102/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a case when you need *adaptive word boundaries* (the term I prefer using). As all terms you have start with a word char, you can go on using `\b` as your left-hand boundary.

The right-hand boundary is either `\b` (if the last char is a word char) or *no boundary check at all* since you do not care if there is a word or a non-word char after `-`.

You can use a regex escape function like

```vb
Function RegexEscape(text As String) As String
Dim rx As New regExp
With rx
    .pattern = "[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
End With
RegexEscape = rx.Replace(text, "\$&")
End Function
```

and then use this with the adaptive word boundaries like

```vb
.pattern = "(?!\B\w)" & RegexEscape(search_criteria)  & "(?!\B\w)"
```

**Legacy answer**

You can also build the boundaries "manually":

```vb
Function BuildBoundaryPattern(pattern As String) As String
BuildBoundaryPattern = "\b" & pattern
If Right(pattern, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z0-9_]" Then
    BuildBoundaryPattern = BuildBoundaryPattern & "\b"
End If
End Function
```

This will build the right pattern for each check.

See a test sub:

```vb
Sub TestBBP()
Dim vbRegX As Object, vbRegXMatch As Object, pattern As String
Dim arr() As String: arr = Split("dogs -,cats -,cats and dogs,houses,cars,work -", ",")

For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
  Set vbRegX = New regExp
  vbRegX.pattern = BuildBoundaryPattern(arr(x))
  If vbRegX.Test(arr(x) & " sleeping") Then
    Debug.Print ("'" & arr(x) & "' in '" & arr(x) & " sleeping' matched!")
  End If
  If vbRegX.Test(arr(x) & "Sleeping") Then
    Debug.Print ("'" & arr(x) & "' in '" & arr(x) & " sleeping' matched!")
  End If
  Debug.Print ("------")
Next x
End Sub
```

Output:

```
'dogs -' in 'dogs - sleeping' matched!
'dogs -' in 'dogs - sleeping' matched!
------
'cats -' in 'cats - sleeping' matched!
'cats -' in 'cats - sleeping' matched!
------
'cats and dogs' in 'cats and dogs sleeping' matched!
------
'houses' in 'houses sleeping' matched!
------
'cars' in 'cars sleeping' matched!
------
'work -' in 'work - sleeping' matched!
'work -' in 'work - sleeping' matched!
------
```

Comment: This reply is extremely useful as there is a part in this code that I can use on mine.  

Since some strings in the array have "-" at the end of the string and I need to map the string from the array plus the "-" in the string, I could do something like this:  

**BuildBoundaryPattern = "\b" & pattern  

If Right(pattern,1) Like "-" Then  
    BuildBoundaryPattern = BuildBoundaryPattern & "\W"  
Else  
  BuildBoundaryPattern = BuildBoundaryPattern & "\b"  
End if**

Comment: But, will it cause the output to be the same if I do: **"\b" & search_pattern "\W"**
Meaning, the code will look for a string (a word or sets of words) that can or not end in "-"?

Comment: @denisse Feel free to edit the boundary pattern as per your needs. `\W` matches any non-word char, and exactly one.